# Trouble with calling methods in c#

Tags: c#, methods, return

I am working on something for an intro level c# calss and I am having an incredibly hard time figuring out methods.  The book does not seem to be very clear in some instances.  For my current assignment I am trying to make a program that calculates the cost of a hospital stay. We need to have three different methods for the program.  I feel like I have the methods at least created correctly but I am unsure as to how make the program output the things from those methods during the button click event.  Here is what I have so far(I have tried about a million different things in the calcBtn_Click method and I am firmly confused).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int CalcStayCharges()
        {
            int lengthOfStay;
            lengthOfStay = int.Parse(dayStayed.Text);
            int totalStayCharges = (350 * lengthOfStay);
            return totalStayCharges;
        }

        private double CalcMiscCharges()
        {
            double medCharges;
            medCharges = double.Parse(medCharge.Text);

            double surgCharges;
            surgCharges = double.Parse(surgicalCharge.Text);

            double labFees;
            labFees = double.Parse(labFee.Text);

            double rehabCharges;
            rehabCharges = double.Parse(rehabCharge.Text);

            double MiscCharge = (medCharges + surgCharges + labFees + rehabCharges);
            return MiscCharge;
        }


        public double CalcTotalCharges()
        {


            double miscCharges = CalcMiscCharges();
            int stayCharges = CalcStayCharges();
            double totalCharges = miscCharges + stayCharges;
            return totalCharges;

        }


        private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           MessageBox.Show(CalcTotalCharges());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the issue??

Comment: Do you get a message box?  Does it just have the wrong number?  Do you know how to use the debugger, set breakpoints, and use the watch window?

Comment: Seems like you have it correct. WHere is the problem?

Comment: MessageBox.Show takes a string, so you may have to say `MessageBox.Show(CalcTotalCharges().ToString());`

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard, that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: @TimKister glad to hear it. If you post the error up front next time, someone will figure it out much faster :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I am still trying to get used to the etiquette of this site. :)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you will have to assign the value that will be returned from a method to a variable and then show/display that variable. For example:

```
int stayCharcges = CalcStayCharges();
```

Let's say that in the textbox a user filled in '3'. Then `stayCharges` will be '1050'. Now you can show it in a label or display it through a MessageBox:

```
ResultLabel.Text = String.Format("Charge: {0}", stayCharges);
//or
ResultLabel.Tekst = stayCharges.ToString() //only the number

//With a MessageBox
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Charge: {0}", stayCharge);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the three different things separately, you could do something like:

```
private void calcBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string display = "Stay Charges: " + CalcStayCharges() + Environment.NewLine +
                     "Misc Charges: " + CalcMiscCharges() + Environment.NewLine + 
                     "Total Charges: " + CalcTotalCharges();

     MessageBox.Show(display);
}
```

Here, I am building a string that I will pass to MessageBox.Show().  MessageBox.Show() expects a string parameter, but you are currently passing a double.  That string adds some English text to explain what each number is, and displays the number.  `Environment.NewLine` causes each charge to appear on a separate line in the message box.

Answer (score 0):

Drop some labels onto your form called:

- lblStayCharge
- lblMiscCharge
- lblTotalCharge

and then in your click event:

```
lblMiscCharge.Text = Convert.ToString(CalcMiscCharges());
lblStayCharge.Text = Convert.ToString(CalcStayCharges());
lblTotalCharge.Text = Convert.ToString(CalcTotalCharges());
```

Your **CalcTotalCharges** method can also be refined to:

```
  public double CalcTotalCharges()
    {
       return CalcMiscCharges() + CalcStayCharges();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

A more robust approach to validating the input from the GUI.

```
private int CalcStayCharges()
{
   int lengthOfStay;
   if (int.TryParse(dayStayed.Text, out lengthReturnOfStay))
   {
      return 350 * lengthOfStay; 
   }
   return 0;       
}


    private double CalcMiscCharges()
    {
        double medCharges;
        double labFees;
        double surgCharges;
        double rehabCharges;

        if (double.TryParse(medCharge.Text, out medCharges) && 
            double.TryParse(surgicalCharge.Text, out surgCharges) &&
            double.TryParse(labFee.Text, out labFees) &&
            double.TryParse(rehabCharge.Text, out rehabCharges)
           )  
        {
            return (medCharges + surgCharges + labFees + rehabCharges);
        }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that second part.  That is a lot cleaner than what I was attempting to use.